# Using RequestMapping "/" in Internet Explorer

Tags: java, spring, internet-explorer, spring-mvc

I have a strange problem. I have an abstract Controller which is extended by another controller. In the abstract class, I have a Request Mapping like

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/", method = RequestMethod.GET)
```

In the extended controller, I have a Request Mapping at the class level, something like

```
@RequestMapping("/myUrl/do")
```

and then I have a method level request Mapping

```
@RequestMapping(value="/", method = RequestMethod.GET, produces = "text/html")
```

Everything works fine in Chrome, but when I use the URL like /myUrl/do/, the method in the super class (the abstract controller) gets executed.
If I use the same Url in chrome, the method in the extended controller gets executed, which according to me should be the expected behavior.

Can't figure out what's happening here..

Comment: I think IE is not preparing the URL correctly..It will be preparing url as / and not /myurl/do..just inspect the URL created in IE using IE developer tool..

Answer (score 0):

Well, I found the reason why... When clicked in IE, it does not specify Accept header. And chrome I guess does specify. Due to this, in case of chrome, the method in the extended controller gets called and in case of IE, the method in the super class gets called (which does not specify any produces attribute).